# floated ul collapsing, causing child li to wrap below each other instead appearing in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a div (.user-band), inside it there is one div (.user-block) floated to left and one UL (.user-stats) floated to right.

Now the issue is when I'm giving width/min-width in percentage to child 'li' items of 'ul' (.user-stats). The 'li' items are not appearing in a row within 'ul', but if i'm giving the same width in pixel (i.e. 250px) they are appearing in a row.

Can anyone please let me know whats going wrong here.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix user-band">
                    <div class="clearfix user-block">
                        <div class="user-pic">
                            <div class="pic-box">
                                <img src="images/user-pic.jpg" alt="">
                            </div> <!--pic-box-->
                        </div> <!--user-pic-->
                        <div class="user-info">
                            <p class="user-id">Martin</p>
                            <p class="user-location"><span class="fa fa-map-marker ic-location"></span> Los Angeles</p>
                        </div> <!--user-info-->
                    </div> <!--user-block-->

                    <ul class="user-stats">
                        <li class="stats-title">
                            Completed Deals
                            <span class="stats-value">15</span>
                        </li>

                        <li class="stats-title">
                            Pending Deals
                            <span class="stats-value">7</span>
                        </li>

                        <li class="stats-title no-click">
                            Total Commission
                            <span class="stats-value">$500</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!--user-band-->
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.user-band { border: 1px solid #e26513; background: #F0701B; padding: 10px; }
.user-block { float: left; }
.user-pic, .user-info { float: left; }
.user-info { margin-left: 10px; }
.user-pic { padding: 2px; border-radius: 2px; background: #ffffff; }
.pic-box { overflow: hidden; text-align: center; width: 80px; height: 80px; }
.pic-box > img { max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
.user-id { font-weight: 700; font-size: 18px; color: #ffffff; }
.user-location { color: #ffffff; }
.user-stats { float: right; margin: -10px -10px -10px 0; list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0; }
.user-stats { float: right; margin: -10px -10px -10px 0; list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0; }
.user-stats > li { display: inline-block; min-width: 250px; padding: 24px 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #e26513; margin-left: -4px; cursor: pointer; }
.user-stats > li:hover { box-shadow: 0 0 200px #e26513 inset; }
.stats-value { font-weight: 700; display: block; font-size: 25px; }
.user-stats > li.no-click { cursor: auto; }
.user-stats > li.no-click:hover { box-shadow: none; }
.ic-location { font-size: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width on the UL - because it is floated.

http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/IeDCd/

#### 15 Apr - Pen updated

See updated pen, what that what you mean?

Note - made code a little more semantic but not perfect.

Comment: Adding `width:100%'` bring ul in the next row, makes `float:right;` property meaningless. My purpose with UL as `float:right` is to keep whole ul bunch in the same row next to `.user-block` element. And I want to give li items a width in percentage, so they will auto adjust in width when go in responsive view.